# No logro que mi boton en Java se muestre dentro de mi JFrame

Tags: java

El problema es que tengo el JFrame y se muestra perfecto, con su titulo y demas. Cuando trato de instanciar un boton, no se muestra en ninguna coordenada que le agrege.

```
    package neuronaia;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MainWindow extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame Ap = new JFrame();
    Ap.setLayout(null);
    Ap.setSize(500,500);
    Ap.setTitle("Aprendizaje");
    Ap.setDefaultCloseOperation(Ap.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Ap.setVisible(true);
    Ap.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Aceptar");
    button1.setBounds(15, 15, 45, 15);      



}

}
```

Comment: Y donde añades el boton al JFrame?
Ap.add(button1);

Comment: Si, muchas gracias. Luego de revisar un proyecto viejo me di cuenta de que habia estado haciendo mal y es esto mismo. Tenia 3-4 meses sin hacer nada en Java

Comment: Solo considera también que estás extendiendo de JFrame y dentro de tu main estas creando otro JFrame, por lo que todos tus métodos que crees en MainWindow no los verás en Ap.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en ese código no agregas el botón que creas al panel. Para ello debes agregar lo siguiente:

```
Ap.add(button1);
```